# tmux set -g mouse-select-window not working

Tags: unix, tmux

from what I understand

```
set -g mouse-select-window on
```

Should allow me to click on a window in the status bar and go to that window. I put that in my tmux.conf file though and nothing happens when I click on a window. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried something like http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/reloading-tmux-config?

Comment: No, that doesn't work. I try to click on a different window but all it does is select that text, doesn't actually change the window.

Comment: Works for me -- tmux 1.5, xterm 281.  Which terminal emulator do you use and is it configured to send mouse events?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my .tmux.conf I have the following:

```
set -g mode-mouse on
set -g mouse-select-window on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
```

Do you have the `mode-mouse on` setting?

Comment: Wow! That worked! I had setw instead of set, I guess that was the issue. Though looking back it seems like I originally had set and not setw. Maybe its because Im using Putty now instead of a mac terminal. Thanks for answering the question almost a year after though!

Answer (score 15):

On 2.1 this config got deprecated and the new option to allow all mouse support is:

```
set -g mouse on
```

This break the nice mouse scroll support, but can be enabled with this:

```
bind -n WheelUpPane if-shell -F -t = "#{mouse_any_flag}" "send-keys -M" "if -Ft= '#{pane_in_mode}' 'send-keys -M' 'select-pane -t=; copy-mode -e; send-keys -M'"
```